# How to remove space/TAB from command output

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Please advice about the following understanding problem ???

I type on my linux machine this: ( in order to get the total memory by top command )

```
top -n1 | grep Mem: 
Mem:   2075024k total,  2059064k used,    15960k free,   249212k buffers
```

so now I want to get the total memory that exists in the second field so I do this:

```
  #  top -n1 | grep Mem: | awk '{print $2}'
```

**but no any results !!!**   -:(

but if I do this: ( the third field ) , then I get the total value in spite the value exists in the **second** field ??

```
 # top -n1 | grep Mem: | awk '{print $3}'
 2075024k
```

any way I want to use the normal command this: ( awk '{print $2}'  )

```
    top -n1 | grep Mem: | awk '{print $2}'
```

please advice what need to add to the "normal" command in order to get the second value - **2075024k** - what’s wrong here ????

```
 # top -n1 | grep Mem: | od -c
  0000000   M   e   m   :     033   (   B 033   [   m 033   [   3   9   ;
  0000020   4   9   m 033   (   B 033   [   m           2   0   7   5   0
  0000040   2   4   k     033   (   B 033   [   m 033   [   3   9   ;   4
  0000060   9   m   t   o   t   a   l   , 033   (   B 033   [   m 033   [
  0000100   3   9   ;   4   9   m 033   (   B 033   [   m           2   0
  0000120   5   8   6   5   6   k     033   (   B 033   [   m 033   [   3
  0000140   9   ;   4   9   m   u   s   e   d   , 033   (   B 033   [   m
  0000160 033   [   3   9   ;   4   9   m 033   (   B 033   [   m        
  0000200           1   6   3   6   8   k     033   (   B 033   [   m 033
  0000220   [   3   9   ;   4   9   m   f   r   e   e   , 033   (   B 033
  0000240   [   m 033   [   3   9   ;   4   9   m 033   (   B 033   [   m
  0000260               2   5   0   5   0   0   k     033   (   B 033   [
  0000300   m 033   [   3   9   ;   4   9   m   b   u   f   f   e   r   s
  0000320 033   (   B 033   [   m 033   [   3   9   ;   4   9   m 033   [
  0000340   K  \n
  0000342
```

Comment: Do: `top -n1 | grep Mem: | od -c` to see if there are any hidden characters in there. In my answer to a previous question, I used the `-b` option to top which removed some highlighting.

Comment: see my update: in the question ...

Comment: You see all those ANSI sequences? `$2` is  `\e(B\e[m\e[39;49m\e(B\e[m` (where `\e` is octal character 033). Try using `top -b -n1`

Comment: @glennjackman you should post that as the answer and finish it off with the correct awk command.

Comment: Why are you using top? Why not `free -m -t`?

Comment: `top` isn't built for programmatic consumption anyhow; its output is intended for humans. If you want to parse something, pick something which is actually sufficiently well-defined that you have a prayer of a chance of your code still working with a different TERM variable defined or in a future release.

Comment: hi Charles - the problem is that on some linux version the command free not exist , maybe this is the reason that he use the top command

Comment: How about `awk`ing out one of the first few lines in `/proc/meminfo` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '/^MemTotal:/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo
```

Output (e.g.), unit: kB:

```
3095532
```

Or:

```
grep -oP "^MemTotal: *\K[^ ]+" /proc/meminfo
```

Output (e.g.), unit: kB:

```
3095532
```